# AWS: Preemptively configure LambdaEdge log groups using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

If given the correct permissions, Lambda functions will automatically create CloudWatch log groups to hold log output from the Lambda. Same for LambdaEdge functions with the addition that the log groups are created in each region in which the LambdaEdge function has run and the name of the log group includes the name of the region. The problem is that the retention time is set to forever and there is no way to change that unless you wait for the log group to be created and then change the retention config after the fact.

To address this, I would like to create those log groups preemptively in Terraform. The problem is that the region would need to be set in the `provider` meta argument or passed in the `providers` argument to a module. I had originally thought that I could get the set of all AWS regions using the `aws_regions` data source and then dynamically create a provider for each region. However, there is currently no way to dynamically generate providers (see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24476).

Has anyone solved this or a similar problem in some other way? Yes, I could create a script using the AWS CLI to do this, but I'd really like to keep everything in Terraform. Using Terragrunt is also an option, but I wanted to see if there were any solutions using pure Terraform before I go that route.

Comment: For LambdaEdge, I'm assuming you are triggering from CloudFront? If that's the case it will automatically create logs in the right region depending on where it is being invoked from. If you are deploying other normal Lambda functions to other regions, then presumably you know which region you are deploying to and you can create the Log Group in the correct region.

Comment: My question pertained only to LambdaEdge functions and was about solutions to be able to set the log retention for the LambdaEdge logs that are automatically created in each region.

Comment: You know the function name so you can just create the Log Group with whatever settings you want ahead of time? Just create an array of the region's you want, or all of them and iterate through to create the logs groups.

Comment: Thank you @TerrySposato. Although you can iterate over a collection of region names, there doesn't seem to be a way to dynamically generate providers for each of those regions which would be required to create a resource in each of those regions. (See the link I included in 2nd paragraph of my question.)

Comment: Well it took me a while but I finally see your dilemma! Might be an interesting feature request to terraform...